# Why is Entitys mapped field NULL after fetch even it is persisted with CascadeType.ALL?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one

I have a business in which I have agencies and backlogs. One Agency has one backlog.

I have a query that allow me to retrieve all agencies, but I get an NPE when trying to access backlog of the agencies retrieved.

When I get a saved object in JPA, shouldn't I have the associated objects as well ?

Here are my entities and service:

**Agency**

```
@NamedQuery(name="allAgences", query="select a from Agency a")
@Stateless
@Entity
public class Agency implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, orphanRemoval = true, 
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="agency", 
            targetEntity=Backlog.class )
    private Backlog backlog;

    public Agency(String name, Backlog backlog) {
        this.name = name;
        this.backlog = backlog;
    }

    public Agency() {
        this.setName("");
        this.setBacklog(new Backlog());
    }
}
// getters, setters...
```

**Backlog**

```
@Stateless
@Entity
public class Backlog implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @OneToOne(optional = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "agency_id")
   private Agency agency;

   public Backlog() {}
    //getters, setters....
}
```

**My Ejb Service**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AgencyBean implements AgencyBeanRemote {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   /**
    * Default constructor. 
    */
   public AgencyBean() {}

   @Override
   public Agency createAgency(String agencyName) {
      Agency agency = new Agency();
      agency.setBacklog(new Backlog());
      agency.getBacklog().setEntries(new ArrayList<>());
      agency.setName(agencyName);
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.persist(agency);
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      return agency;
   }

   @Override
   public List<Agency> getAllAgencies() {
      Query q = em.createNamedQuery("allAgences");
      List<Agency> agencies = q.getResultList();
      for(Agency agency : agencies) {            
   //    System.out.println("hello " + agency.getBacklog().getId());
   // give me a NPE
      }
      return agencies;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the NPE is because `backlog` is `null` in `agency.getBacklog().getId()`

If you take a look on the database and table `backlog` I think you see that `agency_id` is `null`. Therefore `Backlog`s cannot be attached to `Agency`.

To fix this change - in your `public createAgency(String agencyName)`-  row

```
agency.setBacklog(new Backlog());
```

to rows

```
Backlog backlog = new Backlog();
agency.setBacklog(backlog);
backlog.setAgency(agency); // this should do the fix
```

And just to mention - namely if I guessed the NPE reason correct - you have

```
@OneToOne(optional = true ...
private Backlog backlog;
```

so you should expect `backlog` also to be `null` but you do not check that in your code? (Yes I realize that it is possibly only for a test purposes but just to to mention)

Related: [Persist OneToOne relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380008/persist-onetoone-relation-with-springdata-jpa)

**Update**

In `Entity` `Agency` you can also implement following

```
@PrePersist
private void prePersist() {
   // add needed NPE checks etc...
   backlog.setAgency(this);
}
```

This might reduce boilerplate code since there is no more need to add this `backlog.setAgency(agency)` everywhere `Agency` is created the way you do it.

Comment: thanks this fixed my problem, I did not know that you also need to have  backlog.setAgency(agency);. and yes I check if backlog is not null in my code, I just didn't put all here.

Comment: @hamdalaye Glad to know. I found something related and added a link to my answer in case you are interested to read mote about this.